# Prolog - Solve Logic Puzzle

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

I'm trying to experiment with Prolog and wanted to be able to use it to solve an LSAT problem question.

I wrote the following:

```
actor("Mark",B):-
        B >= 0,
        B < 5,
        D < B,
        actor("Jeff", D).

actor("Jeff",C):-
        C >= 0,
        C < 5.
```

My goal was to get the inference: actor("Mark",0). is false.

Whenever I type actor("Mark",0)., I get the following error:

```
ERROR: </2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
   Exception: (7) actor("Mark", 0) ?
```

Does anyone know how I can get Mark to reference Jeff properly? I feel that the problem has something to do with the variable, D, in Mark.

Comment: You better use a constraint programming library for this.

Comment: Basic numeric comparison operators require that all arguments be instantiated. In this specific case, in the term `D < B`, `D` has no value so Prolog is unable to do the comparison. As Willem suggests, you can use the CLPFD library.